# implicit conversion loses integer precision 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'int' when making app?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I was coding, and ran across this..

I don't understand why this is happening and I need help, can someone please help? :)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
Start = YES;
Obstacle.hidden = YES;
Obstacle2.hidden = YES;
Bottom1.hidden = YES;
Bottom2.hidden = YES;
Bottom3.hidden = YES;
Bottom4.hidden = YES;
Bottom5.hidden = YES;
Bottom6.hidden = YES;
Bottom7.hidden = YES;
Top1.hidden = YES;
Top2.hidden = YES;
Top3.hidden = YES;
Top4.hidden = YES;
Top5.hidden = YES;
Top6.hidden = YES;
Top7.hidden = YES;

Heli.center = CGPointMake(48, 145);

HighScore = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"HighScoreSaved"]; < issue HERE

Intro3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"High Score: %i", HighScore];
```

Answer (score 5):

`integerForKey` returns an NSUInteger value (aka unsigned long). I assume your HighScore variable is an int, which has less bytes than a long. Try casting to int:

```
HighScore = (int)[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"HighScoreSaved"];
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing it's in your second to last line. `integerForKey:` returns a NSUInteger (unsigned long), and HighScore is probably declared as an int (you don't show the declaration in your code). Either explicitly cast it using `(int)`, or store it as an int in the user defaults (`intForKey:`). Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It would have been nice if you had included the declaration for `HighScore`, but I will assume it is an `int` because this is the type you are having trouble with. When you are assigning `HighScore` to the result of `-[NSUserDefaults integerForKey:]` you are assigning a variable of type `NSUInteger` to type `int`. This is the root of your problem. Because `NSUInteger` is typedef'd to `unsigned long` and `long` is a larger representation of a number than `int`, during assignment, you are losing precision. I have two recomendations.

```
@property (nonatomic) NSUInteger HighScore; // declare HighScore as NSUInteger

/* or */

HighScore = (int)[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"HighScoreSaved"];
```

The first simply declares HighScore as a NSUInteger to avoid the problem in the first place, the second casts the return type of the method to fit its assignment.

Comment: n.b. declaring it as NSUInteger is a good idea, but then be sure to change the string format specifier in stringWithFormat as %i won't do anymore. (I think it's %ul ? I recall with 64-bit support in XCode 5.1 I had to change to some odd specifier and cast NSUInteger to make these portable)